# Select a specific cell from table

Tags: php, mysql

I know it must be something very silly I'm missing here. I have a table and all calculations are working great. I'm stuck here:

After while loop I can echo ttl_sold and all other information everything except "balance".

in while loop these are fine and I get results:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql); ?>

<?php
$sum = $sum + $rows['total'];
$ttlsold = $ttlsold + $rows['quantity'];
?>


<?php

$sum = 0;
$ttlsold = 0;

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

ttl_sold is 12 and when I echo "balance" I get -12. I did try to include this within the loop and outside, but still no luck!

```
<?php
$balance = "SELECT stock FROM tbl_name WHERE id = 1";
$balance = $balance - $ttl_sold;
?>

<table width="1000" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td width="100"><?php echo $balance; ?></td>
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: $balance is the SQL statement as a string variable.... you're not executing the SQL query or getting the result... suggest you look at the PHP manual for the basics of database access.... and learn PDO (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) rather than the deprecated MySQL that most people will suggest

Comment: Please show us the entire relevant code, including the part where you execute the query and the loop you speak of.

Comment: Thanks. Added the other parts.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
$query = "SELECT stock FROM tbl_name WHERE id = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $balance = $row['stock'];
    $balance = $balance - $ttl_sold;
}
```

- [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

The article below talks about `SQL Injection` but it introduces how to use new PHP Extensions such as `PDO` and `MySQLi`.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated, why not to tell beginners about mysqli?

Comment: As I suspected, he actually _is_ executing the query (he just edited)

Comment: Thanks all. I got it done. I actually had to run 2 queries at the same time before the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something like this:

```
$balance = "SELECT stock FROM tbl_name WHERE id = 1" - 12;
// PHP makes:
$balance = (int) "SELECT stock FROM tbl_name WHERE id = 1" - 12;
// And moreover:
$balance = 0 - 12;
$balance = -12;
```

You have to execute this query first, for MySQL you can use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).